# Django form init override 'Select a valid choice' form validation error

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to override the `__init__` method to update the queryset on the `roles` field of my form. This is throwing a validation error which says:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

..then returns the form with no options in this `roles` field.

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    role = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=EmployeeType.objects.all(),
        empty_label=None,
        required=False)
    supervisor = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Employee.objects.all(),
        required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.company = (kwargs.pop('company', None))
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].queryset = EmployeeType.objects.filter(company=self.company)
        self.fields['supervisor'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(company=self.company, supervisor=None)
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            employee = Employee.objects.get(username=form.instance)
            user_count = request.tenant.employee_set.count()
            if user_count > 1:
                form.instance.is_active = False
            if form.instance.role:
                group_obj = form.instance.role.group
                group = Group.objects.get(name=group_obj)
                employee.groups.add(group)
            company = request.tenant
            form.instance.company = company
            return redirect('verify-redirect')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm(company=request.tenant)
    return render(request, 'employees/register.html', {'form': form})
```

How do I fix the form validation error?

Comment: Can you share the view that initialises the form?

Comment: Absolutely! I was hoping it wasn't needed :) One sec..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the request method is POST you are not passing `company` when you initialise the form

```
form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
```

This is causing you to set the queryset for the `role` field to `EmployeeType`s where company is null

```
# self.company will be None
self.fields['role'].queryset = EmployeeType.objects.filter(company=self.company)
```

You need to pass company

```
form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, company=request.tenant)
```